# Issue scaling down height of image and divs - CSS /

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am working on this site where I need to scale columns of divs (containing images) dependent on the height of the window. I've got it working in safari (but not chrome or firefox) I've been reading a lot and can't find an answer to my particular problem. I tried some javascript stuff to fix it, but couldn't work it out.

http://wolvesvslions.com/sarah_new_site/

It looks fine every time it loads, but I have two issues after scaling.

1.) When shrinking the window the image doesn't scale it's width down, only it's height scales. (due to it's div not scaling width)

2.) When you size up it scales the image, but not the div (masking off a portion of the image)

Any help would be appreciated! Hopefully this is just me not knowing what I am doing.

Comment: is there a way through javascript to set the width of my div to a percentage of the window height? so say my div's height is 50% and my width would then be 50% of window height making it a perfect square?

Answer (score 0):

change incase class

min-width: 0px;
heght: 100%;
width: 100%
overflow-y:hidden;

Comment: that didn't fix the issue. The only reason my width is large is to keep it from collapsing the columns into rows.